# On the number of cosets of a sublattice in a lattice

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, integer-lattices

In several questions, e.g. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805955/what-is-a-coset-in-a-lattice-and-how-many-they-are), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2648447/mathrmcard-mathbbzn-m-mathbbzn-detm?noredirect=1&lq=1), it has been asked why the [index of a sublattice $M\mathbb{Z}^n$ in $\mathbb{Z}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245733/index-of-a-sublattice-in-a-lattice-and-a-homomorphism-between-them?rq=1) is equal to $\det(M)$, that is $|\mathbb{Z}^n/M\mathbb{Z}^n|=\det(M)$. The answer to this question seems to be quite theoretical, and I was wondering if there was a more intuitive approach similar to the explanation in [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805955/what-is-a-coset-in-a-lattice-and-how-many-they-are) (specifically I have trouble understanding the statements "The cosets of L are precisely (a,b)+L, where (a,b) is an integer point that belongs to B(X). The number of those points is the area of B(X), which is det(B).")

Moreover in my current studies I often encounter the situation of a "general" lattice $A\mathbb{Z}^n\subset\mathbb{Z}^n$ being quotiented by a sublattice $M\mathbb{Z}^n$ as $A\mathbb{Z}^n/M\mathbb{Z}^n$ and I have reason to believe that $|A\mathbb{Z}^n/M\mathbb{Z}^n|=\frac{\det(M)}{\det(A)}$. I have not been able to find a reference for it, and it might not be true. However as an example we have for 
\begin{align*}
A=(v_1 v_2 v_3 v_4)=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ -1 & 3 & -1 & 1\\ -1 & 1 & 3 & -1\\ -1 & -1 & 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \text{ and } M=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 3 & 3 & 3\\ 3 & 3 & -3 & -3\\ -3 & 3 & 3 & -3\\ -3 & 3 & -3 & 3 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
that $\frac{\det(M)}{\det(A)}=9$ and one can show that the nontrivial cosets of $M$ are given by $M\pm v_i$, $i=1,2,3,4$.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the second isomorphism theorem for groups to see that you are correct:

$$\frac{\Bbb Z / M\Bbb Z}{A\Bbb Z / M\Bbb Z} \cong \frac{\Bbb Z}{A\Bbb Z}.$$

Therefore

$$\frac{\det M}{|A\Bbb Z / M\Bbb Z|} = \det A.$$

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. However according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Second_isomorphism_theorem) that result seems to stem from the third isomorphism theorem, or am I missing something from the statement of the second?  Also: do you happen to in addition sit on some insight regarding my first problem of seeing the original result as more geometric rather than algebraic?

Comment: What wikipedia calls the third, I called the second isomorphism theorem. Unfortunately the nomenclature isn't standardized at all here -- I've seen what's usually called the first theorem called both the $0$th and the third...
I'll edit my answer in case I can come up with a more geometric approach.