# Size of $ \mathbb{Z}^m/\Lambda$, for $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{Z}^m$

Tags: group-theory, cryptography, integer-lattices, quotient-group

To be specific my question is how to determine $| \mathbb{Z}^m/\Lambda_q^{\bot}(A)|$ which
$$\Lambda_q^{\bot}(A) = \{y =\mathbb{Z}^m \mid Ay =0 \bmod q \}$$
for full rank $A_{q}^{n*m}$ that $m\geq n$ and $q$ a prime(a q-ary lattice). And more generally what is $| \mathbb{Z}^m/\Lambda|$ when $\Lambda$ is a additive subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^m$(a general integer lattice)?

Comment: To find the structure of ${\mathbb Z}^m/\Lambda$, you calculate the Smith Normal Form of the matrix defining $\Lambda$.

Comment: Could you please explain more? What do you mean by **the matrix defining** $\Lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotient $\mathbb{Z}^m/\Lambda$ is the quotient group of cosets $x + \Lambda$ with $x \in \mathbb{Z}^m$. Each $x+ \Lambda$ is a shift (translation) of $\Lambda$ by $x$. Then $|\mathbb{Z}^m/\Lambda|$ is the volume of $\Lambda$. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805955/what-is-a-coset-in-a-lattice-and-how-many-they-are) is more extensive on this.

For $\Lambda = \Lambda^{\perp}_q(A)$, note that $\Lambda$ is the kernel of the composition homomorphism $a:\mathbb{Z}^m \to (\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^m \to (\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^n$, where the first arrow is reduction modulo $q$ and the second arrow sends $x$ to $Ax$. Since $A$ has full rank, $a$ is surjective. Therefore, by the isomorphism theorem, there is a group isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}^m/\ker(a) \simeq (\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^n$. Therefore it follows $|\mathbb{Z}^m/\Lambda^\perp_q(A)| = |\mathbb{Z}^m/\ker(a)| = q^n$.